# How put together rotated table and paragraphs in a same page in LATEX?

Tags: tables, rotating

I use "rotating" package to rotate my table in LATEX. It rotates my table in a page lonely. I want to put paragraphs in right side of the rotated table. Is there any solution?

my used code is:

```
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{sidewaystable*}[!htbp]

\caption{...}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}

..... data

\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable*}
```

Comment: How should the caption be aligned in terms of the table? Say, sideways table with regular caption and regular text?

Comment: I did not understand well! In my code, Caption is also rotated 90 degree with table rotation. My main concern is that in a page, can i use both rotated table and some texts (paragraph)? Or, if we rotate a table, this table occupies whole a page? We can not use empty spaces of the page?

Comment: A `sidewaystable` float always use a full page. You should use `table` and rotate only the `tabular`.

Comment: @egreg : how can i do it? I need to rotate table, then use empty spaces of the page with some other texts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sidewaystable` float always occupies a page by itself. You can use the normal `table` float and rotate only the table inside or both the table and the caption. I'd prefer the first way. Don't use the `h` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table}[tp] % NO h HERE!
\centering

\rotatebox{90}{%
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{lp{7.5cm}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{A} & \textbf{Text} \\
  \midrule
  X & \lipsum*[2] \\
  Y & \lipsum*[2] \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}

\caption{Some caption that shouldn't be rotated}\label{tab:r}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4-9]

\begin{table}[tp]% NO h HERE!
\centering

\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{minipage}{9cm}
  \small\centering
  \begin{tabular}{lp{7.5cm}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{A} & \textbf{Text} \\
  \midrule
  X & \lipsum*[2] \\
  Y & \lipsum*[2] \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
  \caption{Some caption that shouldn't be rotated}\label{tab:s}
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{table}

\lipsum[10-15]


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: for second code, can we copy "\caption{}" outside of the "\rotatebox{90}{" in order to shift Caption up the Table not down?

Comment: @BlueBit If you move the caption outside the `\rotatebox` it won't be rotated. My preference would go to an unrotated caption, if you want it above the table, just move it after `\centering` in the first code.