# Text and sidewaystable on same page

Tags: tables, sectioning, page-breaking, rotating

I have a oversized sidewaystable, that means I have too many rows for my geometry. The oversize prevents my table from appearing on a page with the section. Here is a small example. The section isn't on the same page as the table.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, oneside, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom = 3cm, left =3.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\section{Testsection}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Test: Oversized sidewaystable} 
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  |l|l|S|S|S|S|S|S|S| *{7}{S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post=***]}
}

\hline

\textbf{test1} & {\textbf{test2}} & {\textbf{Number1}} & {\textbf{Number2}} & 
                {\textbf{Number3}} & {\textbf{Number4}} & {\textbf{Number5}} & {\textbf{Number6}} & {\textbf{Number7}} \\ 

\hline\hline 
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Here is my question: How can I get the table on the same page as the section?
I've tried to use [H] like:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[H]
```

But this made the whole table disappear.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Philippe

Comment: The answer will involve "don't use `sidewaystable`", as a `sidewaystable` is always placed on a page of its own.  See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137342/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395435/ helps.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways for this: either you set the font size to `\footnotesize`  and use a smaller value of `\tabcolsep`, and you don't need  `sidewaystable`. Or you use a minipage nested in a `sideways` environment.

Note compilation produces a warning about `scrpage2` being obsolete and having to be replaced with `scrlayer-scrpage`, which I did.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, oneside, headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage[vmargin= 3cm, left =3.5cm, right=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\section{Testsection}

\begin{table}[!htb]%sidewaystable
\centering
\captionabove{Test: Oversized sidewaystable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{
  |l|l| *{7}{S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post=***]|}
}

\hline

\textbf{test1} & {\textbf{test2}} & {\textbf{Number1}} & {\textbf{Number2}} &
                {\textbf{Number3}} & {\textbf{Number4}} & {\textbf{Number5}} & {\textbf{Number6}} & {\textbf{Number7}} \\

\hline\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\section{Testsection}

\begin{sideways}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex}
\begin{minipage}{1.12\textwidth}
\small
\captionaboveof{table}{Test: Oversized sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{
  |l|l| *{7}{S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post=***]|}
}
\hline
\textbf{test1} & {\textbf{test2}} & {\textbf{Number1}} & {\textbf{Number2}} &
               {\textbf{Number3}} & {\textbf{Number4}} & {\textbf{Number5}} & {\textbf{Number6}} & {\textbf{Number7}} \\
\hline\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
test1 & test2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{sideways}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]