# Blank page after subsection in appendix

Tags: sectioning, rotating, appendix, sidewaystable

The table after the subsection title in the Appendix gets moved to the next page, although it would easily fit, afaik, on the page with the subsection title. This gives a page that includes nothing but the subsection title, followed by the table on the next page. I want know how to fit the table right below the subsection title (even if it starts only some millimetres below). Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,english,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]

\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=blue, filecolor=black, menucolor=black, runcolor=black, urlcolor=black}

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section*{Appendix} \label{sec:appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\clearpage
\subsection{XYZ}\label{sec:xyz}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{B.\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{B.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!h]\centering\small
\caption{Table 1.}\label{tab:table1}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
\toprule
          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}\\
\midrule
price\_constant   &   10.073\sym{***}&  13.562\sym{***}&  12.093\sym{***}&   11.232\sym{***}&   11.330\sym{***}&   10.572\sym{***}&   10.036\sym{***}&   10.077\sym{***}&    9.665\sym{***}   \\
price\_sigma    &    4.681\sym{***}& 5.448\sym{***}&   4.756\sym{***}&    4.574\sym{***}&    5.069\sym{***}&    4.596\sym{***}&    4.522\sym{***}&    5.058\sym{***}&    3.827\sym{***}   \\
\midrule
wage\_constant    &    3.342\sym{***}&    5.133\sym{***} &   4.170\sym{***}&    3.687\sym{***}&    3.812\sym{***}&    3.386\sym{***}&    3.166\sym{***}&    3.136\sym{***}&    3.087\sym{***}   \\
wage\_sigma    &    3.068\sym{***}&   3.279\sym{***} &   2.995\sym{***}&    2.790\sym{***}&    3.038\sym{***}&    3.046\sym{***}&    2.594\sym{***}&    2.528\sym{***}&    2.418\sym{***}    \\
\midrule
Observations     &     3104         &      194  &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194          \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
     &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(16)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(17)}\\
\midrule
price\_constant   &    9.655\sym{***}&    9.727\sym{***}&    9.675\sym{***}&    9.464\sym{***}&    9.356\sym{***}&    8.711\sym{***}&    8.065\sym{***}&    7.952\sym{***}\\
price\_sigma    &      4.249\sym{***}&    4.146\sym{***}&    3.892\sym{***}&    3.951\sym{***}&    4.071\sym{***}&    3.819\sym{***}&    3.885\sym{***}&    5.137\sym{***}\\
\midrule
wage\_constant    &    3.229\sym{***}&    3.196\sym{***}&    3.072\sym{***}&    3.157\sym{***}&    3.060\sym{***}&    2.790\sym{***}&    2.709\sym{***}&    2.605\sym{***}\\
wage\_sigma    &     2.617\sym{***}&    2.887\sym{***}&    2.512\sym{***}&    2.625\sym{***}&    2.791\sym{***}&    2.667\sym{***}&    3.918\sym{***}&    4.752\sym{***}\\
\midrule
Observations     & 194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396344/146828 could help you solve your problem too !

Answer (score 3):

Two problems: `sidewaystable` always starts on a new page and the table is too big to fit on the remaining space below the section title. To fix this I suggest a smaller fontsize and a normal table environment and rotate the content :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,english,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]

\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=blue, filecolor=black, menucolor=black, runcolor=black, urlcolor=black}

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}


\appendix
\section*{Appendix} \label{sec:appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\clearpage
\subsection{XYZ}\label{sec:xyz}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{B.\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{B.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{table}[!h]\centering\scriptsize
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{minipage}{.84\textheight}
\caption{Table 1.}\label{tab:table1}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
\toprule
          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}\\
\midrule
price\_constant   &   10.073\sym{***}&  13.562\sym{***}&  12.093\sym{***}&   11.232\sym{***}&   11.330\sym{***}&   10.572\sym{***}&   10.036\sym{***}&   10.077\sym{***}&    9.665\sym{***}   \\
price\_sigma    &    4.681\sym{***}& 5.448\sym{***}&   4.756\sym{***}&    4.574\sym{***}&    5.069\sym{***}&    4.596\sym{***}&    4.522\sym{***}&    5.058\sym{***}&    3.827\sym{***}   \\
\midrule
wage\_constant    &    3.342\sym{***}&    5.133\sym{***} &   4.170\sym{***}&    3.687\sym{***}&    3.812\sym{***}&    3.386\sym{***}&    3.166\sym{***}&    3.136\sym{***}&    3.087\sym{***}   \\
wage\_sigma    &    3.068\sym{***}&   3.279\sym{***} &   2.995\sym{***}&    2.790\sym{***}&    3.038\sym{***}&    3.046\sym{***}&    2.594\sym{***}&    2.528\sym{***}&    2.418\sym{***}    \\
\midrule
Observations     &     3104         &      194  &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194          \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
     &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(16)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(17)}\\
\midrule
price\_constant   &    9.655\sym{***}&    9.727\sym{***}&    9.675\sym{***}&    9.464\sym{***}&    9.356\sym{***}&    8.711\sym{***}&    8.065\sym{***}&    7.952\sym{***}\\
price\_sigma    &      4.249\sym{***}&    4.146\sym{***}&    3.892\sym{***}&    3.951\sym{***}&    4.071\sym{***}&    3.819\sym{***}&    3.885\sym{***}&    5.137\sym{***}\\
\midrule
wage\_constant    &    3.229\sym{***}&    3.196\sym{***}&    3.072\sym{***}&    3.157\sym{***}&    3.060\sym{***}&    2.790\sym{***}&    2.709\sym{***}&    2.605\sym{***}\\
wage\_sigma    &     2.617\sym{***}&    2.887\sym{***}&    2.512\sym{***}&    2.625\sym{***}&    2.791\sym{***}&    2.667\sym{***}&    3.918\sym{***}&    4.752\sym{***}\\
\midrule
Observations     & 194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace
\end{tabular}

\begin{minipage}{17cm} \footnotesize \emph{Notes:} Significance levels: * (p<0.10), ** (p<0.05), *** (p<0.01). \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Perhaps you could a couple of words to say what you have done fix these problems.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on how to also rotate the minipage below the tabular?

Comment: @user3213255 Which minipage?

Comment: Like so:

```
\end{tabular}
}
       \begin{minipage}{17cm}  \footnotesize \emph{Notes:} Significance levels: * \(p<0.10\), ** \(p<0.05\), *** \(p<0.01\).
       \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: @user3213255 Close the `}` after the minipage

Comment: Closing `}` does rotates the minipage, but puts it above the table. I found a different solution posted below. Thanks!

Comment: @user3213255 See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, starting with `minipage` after `rotate box` also works. Now I still need to figure out how to also rotate `caption`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution including table notes works with `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,english,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}[2011/08/13]

\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=blue, filecolor=black, menucolor=black, runcolor=black, urlcolor=black}

\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}


\appendix
\section*{Appendix} \label{sec:appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\clearpage
\subsection{XYZ}\label{sec:xyz}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{B.\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{B.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{table}[!h]\centering\scriptsize
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table 1.}\label{tab:table1}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
\toprule
          &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}\\
\midrule
price\_constant   &   10.073\sym{***}&  13.562\sym{***}&  12.093\sym{***}&   11.232\sym{***}&   11.330\sym{***}&   10.572\sym{***}&   10.036\sym{***}&   10.077\sym{***}&    9.665\sym{***}   \\
price\_sigma    &    4.681\sym{***}& 5.448\sym{***}&   4.756\sym{***}&    4.574\sym{***}&    5.069\sym{***}&    4.596\sym{***}&    4.522\sym{***}&    5.058\sym{***}&    3.827\sym{***}   \\
\midrule
wage\_constant    &    3.342\sym{***}&    5.133\sym{***} &   4.170\sym{***}&    3.687\sym{***}&    3.812\sym{***}&    3.386\sym{***}&    3.166\sym{***}&    3.136\sym{***}&    3.087\sym{***}   \\
wage\_sigma    &    3.068\sym{***}&   3.279\sym{***} &   2.995\sym{***}&    2.790\sym{***}&    3.038\sym{***}&    3.046\sym{***}&    2.594\sym{***}&    2.528\sym{***}&    2.418\sym{***}    \\
\midrule
Observations     &     3104         &      194  &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194          \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
     &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(16)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(17)}\\
\midrule
price\_constant   &    9.655\sym{***}&    9.727\sym{***}&    9.675\sym{***}&    9.464\sym{***}&    9.356\sym{***}&    8.711\sym{***}&    8.065\sym{***}&    7.952\sym{***}\\
price\_sigma    &      4.249\sym{***}&    4.146\sym{***}&    3.892\sym{***}&    3.951\sym{***}&    4.071\sym{***}&    3.819\sym{***}&    3.885\sym{***}&    5.137\sym{***}\\
\midrule
wage\_constant    &    3.229\sym{***}&    3.196\sym{***}&    3.072\sym{***}&    3.157\sym{***}&    3.060\sym{***}&    2.790\sym{***}&    2.709\sym{***}&    2.605\sym{***}\\
wage\_sigma    &     2.617\sym{***}&    2.887\sym{***}&    2.512\sym{***}&    2.625\sym{***}&    2.791\sym{***}&    2.667\sym{***}&    3.918\sym{***}&    4.752\sym{***}\\
\midrule
Observations     & 194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         &      194         \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace
\end{tabular}
       \begin{tablenotes}   \footnotesize \item Significance levels: * \(p<0.10\), ** \(p<0.05\), *** \(p<0.01\).
       \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```