# Sidewaystable taking entire page

Tags: tables, sidewaystable

I am messing around with tutorial on LaTeX, trying to figure out the tables. I want to put the sideways table inline like an ordinary table, to be inbetween the text. But it just puts it on the new page and it takes the entire page for itself.

```
    \begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
  \begin{center}
  \caption{Landscape table.}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{l|S|r}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
    $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
    \midrule
    1 & 1110.1 & a\\
    2 & 10.1 & b\\
    3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: A `sidewaystable` is always placed on a page on its own. From the manual: "The package provides: two new environments, `sidewaystable`and `sidewaysfigure`, each of which produces a single page-size float with contents rotated ±90 degrees;"

Comment: Why would you want to rotate the table in your example? It should fit perfectly into the textwidth already.

Comment: [How put together rotated table and paragraphs in a same page in LATEX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137342/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue but please keep in mind that the horizontal lines from the booktabs package are incompatible with vertical lines.